# Why is the multiplication of the metric and an inverse metric the Kronecker delta?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, linear-algebra

I am having a hard time understanding \begin{align*} \delta_{\beta}^{\alpha}=g^{\alpha\nu}g_{\beta\nu}\\  \end{align*} equality.
I understand the situation where the indices are the same and the result is 1 but, I couldn't wrap my head around the second option where the indices are different and the result is 0.In flat space it holds but I wonder why this holds in a curved space-time. Is it by the definition of it or does it have a proper explanation? If it does, could you explain it?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Note that we use MathJax to typeset mathematics; you can find a good tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). In particular, the formula in your first sentence is missing enough information (regarding the upper/lower placement of the indices) to be interpretable.

Comment: I usually take this as the definition of the inverse metric (just as the definition of $A^{-1}$ is usually $A A^{-1} = 1$, for matrices). What other definition would you use as a starting point?

Comment: I undertand why it is 1 , I am a little confused about the option it is 0. How do we know it is zero?

Comment: Do you understand that the Kronecker delta is just the identity matrix?

Comment: So the same indices are diagonal components and the others are off-diagonal components of the identity matrix?

Comment: The diagonal components of $\delta^\alpha_\beta$ are the ones where $\alpha=\beta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a metric $\mathbf g$ with components $g_{ab}$ which eats two vectors and spits out their inner product, we can construct a *dual* metric $\boldsymbol \Gamma$ with components $\Gamma^{ab}$ which eats two **covectors** and spits out their inner product.  The matrix $\Gamma^{ab}$ is given by the inverse of the matrix $g_{ab}$, i.e.
$$\Gamma^{ab} g_{bc} = \delta^a_c$$

By convention, we write $\Gamma^{ab} \equiv g^{ab}$, with the understanding that we're talking about the dual metric when the indices are upstairs.  So, the answer to your question is that $g^{ab}g_{bc} = \delta^a_c$ provides the **definition** of the dual metric components $g^{ab}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.